# What path will an object in a cockpit take?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Situation:  A fly is in the cockpit of a fighter jet, and flying directly in front of the pilot.  The pilot becomes annoyed and decides to get rid of the fly by executing a sudden, high speed turn. The cockpit is so dark the fly cannot see any of the cockpit.  will the fly continue to be in front of the pilot, or will it hit the side of the cockpit?  If the pilot executes a slow turn will the result be different?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 2):

The fly would move out of the way. The fly (when right in front of the pilots face) has the same forward velocity as the plane. If the airplane accelerated forward then the fly would "fly backwards" (no pun intended) just as you think you do in a car that accelerates quickly. However, this is actually not you flying backwards, it is simply the car going forward faster than your body is. The car seat is what pushes you faster. You need a force to accelerate.

So for the fly as the plane turns, there is no force (no wall, wind, etc.) on the fly, so the fly would move out of the way. It would do this until it hit the wall, then it would continue to accelerate with the plane because it was against the wall of the plane pushing it.

So that being said how do you think the rate at which the plane turns (or accelerates$^{1}$) affects what happens to the fly?

---

1 The plane does not need to change its *speed* (magnitude of velocity) to accelerate* it needs to change the direction of the velocity vector. Google Centripetal acceleration for more about this.